# catching optional part in regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have an input text which can be either:

```
"URL: http://www.cnn.com Cookie: xxx; yyy"
```

or just:

```
"URL: http://www.cnn.com"
```

How do I capture both URL and cookie into two separate variables in Python? The part I don't know how specify is the optional cookie.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str = 'URL: http://www.cnn.com Cookie: xxx; yyy'

match = re.search(r'URL: (\S+)( Cookie: (.*))?', str)
print match.group(1)
print match.group(3)

>>> http://www.cnn.com
>>> xxx; yyy
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know groups can be nested.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

inputstring = "URL: http://www.cnn.com Cookie: xxx; yyy"

if 'Cookie' in inputstring:
    m = re.match('URL: (.*?) Cookie: (.*)', inputstring)
    if m:
        url = m.group(1)
        cookie = m.group(2)
        print url
        print cookie
else:
    m = re.match('URL: (.*)', inputstring)
    if m:
        url = m.group(0)
        print url
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use separate capture groups, and `?` for the optional part of your regex. If a capture group doesn't capture anything the group's value will be `None`.

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'URL: (\S+)(?:\s+Cookie: (\S+))?')
>>> regex.match("URL: http://www.cnn.com Cookie: xxx;yyy").groups()
('http://www.cnn.com', 'xxx;yyy')
>>> regex.match("URL: http://www.cnn.com").groups()
('http://www.cnn.com', None)
```

I've just used `\S+` for the URL and cookie patterns in the above for example purposes. Replace them with your real URL and cookie patterns.

Instead of `groups()` you can use `group(1)` and `group(2)` -- the behavior is the same, but `groups()` is nice with unpacking. eg:

```
url, cookie = match.groups()
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the optional part in (Cookie: xxx; yyy")?